# Does ingress controller support both of a Cloud Run service and a private cluster on GKE?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, google-cloud-run

I have a service implemented on Cloud Run, on the other hand, a multiple services on GKE are same.

Now I would like to all these services to be routed by a same load-balancer, which is deployed with a ingress controller.

According to a Google documented site, there is no information that a ingress controller featured as above can be implemented by a yaml file or command.

For trying, I changed a rule parameter on the yaml file like below.

```yaml
...
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: gke-service-a
          servicePort: 80
        path: /a/*
      - backend:
          serviceName: gke-service-b
          servicePort: 80
        path: /b/*
      - backend:
          serviceName: gke-service-c
          servicePort: 80
        path: /c/v1/d/*
      - backend:
          serviceName: cloud-run-service-z
          servicePort: 80
        path: /c/v1/z/*
...
```

When making ingress, there has been a warning displays 'there is no pods.....',
but now that messages vanished.(I don't know why this happens. no operation after this message displayed.)

Is there any advice or information that ingress controller can routes a request both to cloud run service and gke service?

Comment: Are you running fully managed Cloud Run and a separate GKE cluster or did you enable the Cloud Run on an existing GKE cluster?

Comment: ・ Are you running fully managed Cloud Run 
 
At now, Yes for this and I would like to those services to be routed with a same load-balancer.
 
・ enable the Cloud Run on an existing GKE cluster?
 
No, I didn't.
Is there a way to enable this or a documented information?

Comment: Is the later a Cloud Run for Anthos?In this case, should I subscribe to Anthos?
https://cloud.google.com/kuberun/docs/enabling-on-existing-clusters

Comment: Correct.  You'd follow the steps in the link you found.  Once you've done that, it is then possible to share the same ingress.  See https://cloud.google.com/architecture/integrating-https-load-balancing-with-istio-and-cloud-run-for-anthos-deployed-on-gke

Comment: Thx. I would like to reconsider this issue.

Comment: @GariSingh Looks like your comments answered the question. Can you post those as an actual answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can "share" the same HTTP(S) Load Balancer between Cloud Run and GKE services if you create a [GKE cluster with Cloud Run enabled](https://cloud.google.com/anthos/run/docs/setup#existing_cluster) rather than using the fully managed version of Cloud Run.

Once you've done that, you can follow the detailed guide [here](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/integrating-https-load-balancing-with-istio-and-cloud-run-for-anthos-deployed-on-gke) which explains how to use the same HTTP(S) Load balancer for both Cloud Run and GKE services.  At a high-level,
you'll leverage the Istio component which is deployed as part of Cloud Run to create a virtual gateway for health checks, then you'll need to modify the Istio ingress gateway service so that it can be used with GKE/Kubernetes Ingress and finally you'll create a  GKE / Kubernetes Ingress for the Istio ingress service.